# How to change URL format in MVC 4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Currently my URL looks like this:

```
http://localhost:9737/ProfileEdit?writerId=4
```

But I want it to be something like this:

```
http://localhost:9737/ProfileEdit/4
```

This is my Action signature:

```
public ActionResult ProfileEdit(long writerId)
```

I tried adding new route in RouteConfig file like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
           name: "ProfileEdit",
           url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "ProfileEdit", writerId = UrlParameter.Optional }
       );
```

but no luck.. so how do I change the URL format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You have two ways of doing this:
>
> 1. Change your route values to match the name of the parameter in your action `url: "{controller}/{action}/{writerId}"`.
> 2. Do the opposite and change the parameter name in your action to match the route values `public ActionResult ProfileEdit(long id)`

**Edit**

If you want the same for multiple parameters you need to specify them in the route as well:

> `routes.MapRoute(
>         "ProfileEdit",
>         "{controller}/{action}/{writerId}/{otherParameter}",
>   new { controller = "Home", action = "ProfileEdit", writerId = "", otherParameter = "" });`

Comment: it worked by changing the Action parameter to "public ActionResult ProfileEdit(long id)", and I don't understand why it won't work with writerId

Comment: what do I do for multiple paramters?

Comment: thank you for your answer but this only solves half of my problem. I can't change the format for multiple parameters in the URL

Answer (score 5):

The route defines the parameter as `id`:

```
url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}"
```

But you're using `writerId`:

```
http://localhost:9737/ProfileEdit?writerId=4
```

Change the route to match:

```
url: "{controller}/{action}/{writerId}"
```

Note that this will facilitate this change on *every* URL which uses that route.

Comment: im sorry its not working. It keeps giving this error: "The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'writerId' "

Comment: @TahreemIqbal: For which URL?

Comment: @TahreemIqbal: Shouldn't there be a controller name in that URL too?

Comment: this is the code:  routes.MapRoute(
               name: "ProfileEdit",
               url: "{controller}/{action}/{writerId}",
               defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "ProfileEdit", writerId  = UrlParameter.Optional}
           );

Answer (score 3):

You can add a Route attribute:

```
[Route("ProfileEdit/{writerId}")]
public ActionResult ProfileEdit(long writerId)
```

Comment: The Route attribute is in System.Web.Http. Try adding using System.Web.Http; at the beginning of your Controller.

Answer (score 0):

```
routes.MapRoute(
           name: "ProfileEdit",
           url: "ProfileEdit/{id}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "ProfileEdit"}
       );
```